# setting a CLASSPATH in the script

Tags: classpath, tcsh

I have a script in which I want to set the `CLASSPATH` 
as

> `/dun/d2ddm0/bea/weblogic91/server/lib/jxl.jar:/dun/d2ddm0/bea/user_projects/domains/RMGemDev3023/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/dun/d2ddm0/bea/user_projects/domains/RMGemDev3023/server/lib/parser.jar:/dun/d2ddm0/bea/user_projects/domains/RMGemDev3023/server/lib/jconn2.jar:.`

When I declared in the shell script and then did the export `CLASSPATH` .My script is not working .Could you please tell how can I set the `CLASSPATH` (with the above value) in the script so that my script could recognize it. I use `tcsh` shell.

Answer (score 1):

In tcsh you use setenv instead of export (which is a bash-ism)

So, you should try:

```
setenv CLASSPATH /dun/d2ddm0/bea/weblogic91/server/lib/jxl.jar:/dun/d2ddm0/bea/user_projects/domains/RMGemDev3023/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/dun/d2ddm0/bea/user_projects/domains/RMGemDev3023/server/lib/parser.jar:/dun/d2ddm0/bea/user_projects/domains/RMGemDev3023/server/lib/jconn2.jar:.
```

Good luck.

Comment: Actually I want the CLASSPATH to be defined in a shell script so how would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the comment.  Same way in a shell script.